# Liquid damaged Macbook -- doesn't power up after submerging logicboard in surgical spirit/rubbing alcohol

Tags: macbook-pro, logicboard

I've bought my late 2016 Macbook Pro with Touchbar in February, spilled some juice on it.

Anyway, the machine seemed to function pretty well even so, only the Touchbar was randomly going black. Since the warranty was already voided, I opened it up myself, took pretty much everything out, wiped the components with some rubbing alcohol, then assembled everything back. At this point, the fans were very loud and the battery was alternating between 0% and 50%. None of this was happening BEFORE I disassembled the Macbook.

A few days ago I tried submerging the logicboard in rubbing alcohol (70% isopropylic alcohol, 30% distilled water + blue colouring) for about 48 hours, occasionally brushing it with a clean tootbrush to help lodge some of the orange bits that got stuck. I reassembled it, and now it won't power on at all! I'm not 100% sure I assembled it back correctly. I most likely did, but not being an Apple/Macbook expert...

Does anyone have any idea at all about what might be causing it not to power up? Did the rubbing alcohol damaged the logicboard more than it was already damaged?

Would it help if I wiped/submerged the logicboard in 99% isopropylic alcohol in an ultrasonic bath? I think buying an ultrasonic cleaner will be cheaper than paying $1.200 at Apple.

Any insight would be helpful. Btw, this is my very first (and last) Macbook.

Thanks!
Best regards!

Comment: How did the warranty get voided? Doesn't the warranty last for one year?

Comment: It doesn`t cover liquid damage, unfortunetly.

Comment: do you have bootable USB drive to try from there ? did you try Safe mode, or Restore mode, or is it just plain dead. The Fans and Battery are controlled by the SMC chip, Reset the SMC, observe the charging light flicker to know you did it right.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It's plain dead. It doesn't boot at all, the fans make no noise, and there's nothing to indicate anything is going on when pressing the power button. I tried the SMC reset route but it doesn't work. Also, I don't think the MagSafe charger has a light flicker.

Comment: Sorry, USB-C charger*

Comment: so your keyboard might be a victim as well. If you have a cheep USB keyboard ($10) plug it in and try. Is it showing any life, like the charging light

Comment: @Duchess88 I'm not a hardware person so maybe I don't know but is it normal to submerge logic boards in liquids especially acidic ones for 48 hours? Not a genius here but I would think that would not go well....

Comment: @Buscar웃 I tried your suggestion with the keyboard, but still nothing. It doesn't power up, no light flickers anywhere... It's as if it doesn't have 'power' to start up, if that makes sense.

Comment: @JBis I read about submerging logicboards in rubbing alcohol on the web. Also, I think rubbing alcohol is a very weak acid (pKA of 15.7), according to [this source](https://sciencing.com/properties-isopropyl-alcohol-8299115.html)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, your Mac is done.

Only in very rare cases some survive a liquid spill, but that depends on many factors like the amount of liquid.

As far as I know cleaning will not bring it back the damage is already done. It was powered-up when it happened and you know what liquid does to electronics.

Pretty sure your keyboard also suffered irreparable damage, since the liquid had to pass true it.

For future consideration I recommend preventive action.

this or similar $10 device can save you $1,000

[image]

I have no affiliation with this company.

As a last resort you can try to put in in a Fridge (yes fridge) that should draw out any moisture (Fridge does that).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=18&v=nrXDRvode24

Comment: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3243/263848

Comment: @JBis I'm not sure how this applies here — the question isn't being promotional as far as I can tell, and this answer looks like it is helpfully recommending a product in good faith?

Comment: @grg I agree, I just wanted* to make sure Buscar doesn't get reported by someone else thinking it's promotional, as I have been in the past.